# RubyMine error of No Rails Found in the SDK

Tags: rubymine

I updated to Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0 and RubyMine stopped working.

If I do my Rails commands through command line tool, they work just fine but if I want to run my project through RubyMine (the latest version) I get `error 134` and `No Rails Founds in the SDK` error.

So I am sure it is not a big deal and it is just some minor setting that needs to be updated in the IDE but can't figure it out yet. And not sure what kind of details do I need to provide so here is **Tools -> Show Gem Environment** info from the IDE:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-07-05 patchlevel 251) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Jony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/Jony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/Jony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-darwin-12
GEM PATHS:
   /Users/Jony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head
   /Users/Jony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@global
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   https://rubygems.org/
----------------------
IDE: JetBrains RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1, build #RM-129.861
OS: Mac OS X 10.8.4[x86_64]
Java: 1.6.0_51-b11-456-11M4508
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: RVM: ruby-2.0.0-head
Sdk Version: ver.2.0.0p251 p251
Ruby Interpreter: /Users/Jony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: yes, gemset:[default]
RVM Home: /Users/Jony/.rvm
Sdk Language Level: 1.9
Sdk Load Path:
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/2.0.0
     ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0
     /Applications/RubyMine.app/rubystubs20
Sdk Gem paths: 
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/bundler/gems
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems
     ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@global/gems
Gems used for 'untitled4':
     sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0
     activerecord (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/activerecord-4.0.0
     rack-test (0.6.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/rack-test-0.6.2
     activesupport (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/activesupport-4.0.0
     coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/coffee-script-source-1.6.3
     turbolinks (1.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/turbolinks-1.2.0
     bundler (1.3.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5
     activemodel (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/activemodel-4.0.0
     mail (2.5.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/mail-2.5.4
     rack (1.5.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/rack-1.5.2
     json (1.8.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/json-1.8.0
     minitest (4.7.5)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/minitest-4.7.5
     tzinfo (0.3.37)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/tzinfo-0.3.37
     sass-rails (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/sass-rails-4.0.0
     actionmailer (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0
     hike (1.2.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/hike-1.2.3
     coffee-script (2.2.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0
     activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/activerecord-deprecated_finders-1.0.3
     thread_safe (0.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/thread_safe-0.1.0
     sqlite3 (1.3.7)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7
     sdoc (0.3.20)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/sdoc-0.3.20
     actionpack (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/actionpack-4.0.0
     tilt (1.4.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/tilt-1.4.1
     jquery-rails (3.0.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.2
     mime-types (1.23)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/mime-types-1.23
     railties (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/railties-4.0.0
     sprockets (2.10.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/sprockets-2.10.0
     arel (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/arel-4.0.0
     polyglot (0.3.3)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/polyglot-0.3.3
     thor (0.18.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/thor-0.18.1
     rdoc (3.12.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/rdoc-3.12.2
     rake (10.1.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@global/gems/rake-10.1.0
     coffee-rails (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.0
     i18n (0.6.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/i18n-0.6.4
     multi_json (1.7.7)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/multi_json-1.7.7
     sass (3.2.9)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/sass-3.2.9
     rails (4.0.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/rails-4.0.0
     execjs (1.4.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/execjs-1.4.0
     treetop (1.4.14)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/treetop-1.4.14
     atomic (1.1.10)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/atomic-1.1.10
     erubis (2.7.0)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/erubis-2.7.0
     uglifier (2.1.1)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/uglifier-2.1.1
     jbuilder (1.4.2)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/jbuilder-1.4.2
     builder (3.1.4)
         ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/builder-3.1.4
```

And also a screen shot of my SDK settings just in case:

[image]

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13774.

Comment: gem install rails fixed our problem.

Comment: Did you set the correct ruby version in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 28):

I solved this issue of `No Rails SDK found` by following.

**Step 1.**
Figure out Ruby version and bundle version of your project.
[image: Ruby and bundle version info of my project]

**Step 2.**
Add correct Ruby SDK and GEMs from preferences in Rubymine.
Preferences > Languages & Framework > Ruby SDK and Gems > [Select your RVM version] > [Select correct gem version of bundle] > Apply
[image]

Comment: To see your bundler version run '$ bundle -v'.

Comment: I have already added the same rbenv folder but RubyMine didn't recognize the newly installed bundler version, not even after restarting the IDE. But sitting up rbenv again (pointing to the same folder) was solving the issue (I could see the proper bundler version then in the list, and the server was also starting without issues with the newly added rbenv - which is weird but that's what happened).

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by deleting the project from RubyMine's history (close project and then hit the `x` for the project on the left side) and deleting the .idea directory of my project. After I opened the project in RubyMine again, it worked.

Comment: Deleting the .idea folder deletes all project settings.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer by @atul_vaibhai doesn't work.

Close any open terminals and your project and open your project

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installed another Ruby version ,and it installed in Global file

```
/user/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1
```

The first time I installed the latest Ruby version in my local rvm file, all gem files didn't add in Rubymine which only contains some base ruby files.

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3
```

I don't know why is that,but I don't think I need to know the reason, at least now.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall any new versions of ruby than the one that your application requires.

```
rvm remove <other versions>
```

If this solves your problem, then you need to figure out how to parallely  keep another version without affecting any other application. You must be doing something wrong in configuring the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RubyMine 2023.3.2 in Windows 11 using WSL. The solution is in..

Settings/Languages & Frameworks/Ruby SDK and Gems.

I've got just one Ruby SDK which is a remote interpreter.
In the Right Hand Pane, click on the download icon. It takes a few moments to "Synchronize gems and RubyMine helper files"
Click OK. It now knows about the rails gem in the interpreter.

Can now run the Server.

[image: Remove interpreter with list of gems]

Thanks to vaibhavatul47 for his answer which led me to the correct place. The other answers which suggest you remove and recreate the project will work because on the second iteration you add the remote interpreter after you have done a bundle install. I think this problem comes from having to set up the remote interpreter before the initial bundle install, so you then have to refresh the interpreter with the full list of gems.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error message without updating anything.
*Invalidating the Cache / Restart* worked for me.

[image: InvalidCachInMenue.png]